# interactively replace pixel value

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to develop an "Eraser" tool for imagery as is available in other image editing programs so I can interactively clean up minor defects in imagery by simply mousing over them to set them to a specified color. I did not find such a capability in the Manual or addressed anywhere in this venue. Please direct me to it if I just missed it. Otherwise, I know how to replace pixel values in a static context using ReplacePixelValue. However, in trying to learn Dynamic and do this interactively, the following does not work but I don't know why:

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], image], 
  Dynamic[ReplacePixelValue[image, pt -> 0]]}]
```

I can move the LocatorPane in the left image but nothing happens in the right image although I thought the right image pixel values would be set to 0. Having left and right images is not a requirement in the final version of this tool. I would also like the Eraser point to be a variable size. Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of getting this to work is by using the Locator as a Control of Manipulate.

For the convenience of easier spotting the replaced pixel I have cropped and magnified the image.

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
img = ImageCrop[image, 100];

Manipulate[
 Row@{img, Dynamic@(new = ReplacePixelValue[new, pt -> 0])} // 
  Magnify[#, 10] &, {{pt, {0, 0}}, Locator}, 
 Initialization :> (new = img)]
```

Following your comment here a version with size adjustment of pixel replacer

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{img, 
    Dynamic@First@((new = 
           ReplacePixelValue[new, # -> 0]) & /@ (pt + # & /@ 
          Tuples[Range@sz, 2]))} // Magnify[#, 5] &, {{pt, {0, 0}}, 
  Locator}, {{sz, 1, "Size of pixel replacer "}, 1, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Initialization :> (new = img), 
 SynchronousUpdating -> None]
```

The number of pixels being replaced is the square of the size indicated by the slider

You can spot the replaced pixel as a black spot in the white of Lena's eyeball 
[image]

Comment: @penquin77 Your approach now makes the pixel visible so that's an improvement but can you make the replaced pixel value permanent so as I move the Locator over the white space it permanently replaces the white with black? Also can you replace more than one pixel at a time, say a small square of pixels simultaneously? And then be able to save the modified image for future use.

Comment: no problem  I have modified Dynamic@ (img = ReplacePixelValue[img, pt -> 0]). The result of the Pixel replace is simply assigned to img. Speaking of replacing pixels of a small square. You can simply map this expression over a list of pt, whereas the list of points assigned to pt make up the square for which you want to replace the pixels.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted although it looks more complex than I expected. I also learned more about how to interactively work with images. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Tom , your are welcome, I  just carried out some small tidy-up correction, Now it looks neat and clean. (PS: I like the subject of image processing, yuupi)